# Numpythonic way to perform vector substraction where the operands has different shape each other (a,n) - (b,n)

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, tensor

I have two matrix operand like these:

```
a = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8]])
b = np.array([[9,10], [11,12], [13,14]])
```

If we debug `a` and `b`, they will look like these:

```
[[1 2]
 [3 4]
 [5 6]
 [7 8]]
(4, 2)
int32

[[ 9 10]
 [11 12]
 [13 14]]
(3, 2)
int32
```

I can achieve what I want with this way, where `c` is result:

```
c = []
for i in range(b.shape[0]):
  c.append(b[i] - a)
c = np.array(c)
```

Now, the `c` will be looks like this:

```
[[[ 8  8]
  [ 6  6]
  [ 4  4]
  [ 2  2]]

 [[10 10]
  [ 8  8]
  [ 6  6]
  [ 4  4]]

 [[12 12]
  [10 10]
  [ 8  8]
  [ 6  6]]]
(3, 4, 2)
int32
```

As you see, how I perform substraction was still using `for looping`, is there numpythonic way where I can substract without using loop so that I can utilize numpy optimization therefore the performance will be faster since numpy is using `C language`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8]])
>>> b = np.array([[9,10], [11,12], [13,14]])
>>> b[:, None, :] - a[None, :, :]
    array([[[ 8,  8],
        [ 6,  6],
        [ 4,  4],
        [ 2,  2]],
    
       [[10, 10],
        [ 8,  8],
        [ 6,  6],
        [ 4,  4]],
    
       [[12, 12],
        [10, 10],
        [ 8,  8],
        [ 6,  6]]])
```

Comment: This is the same as @wim, since the leading None is automatic, and so are trailing `:`.  But especially for beginners, making these explicit can be useful.

Comment: Another way to put it, broadcast a (3,1,2) with a (1,4,2) to make a (3,4,2).

Answer (score 2):

To do this directly with numpy array operators would be:

```
b[:, None] - a
```

See [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) in the docs.